# No data when using PuTTY SSH Tunneling

Tags: ssh, python, putty, tunnel

I am trying out SSH tunneling using PuTTY. On my Windows computer, I have PuTTY running with a tunnel going from port 1556 to remoteipaddress:1556. On the remote server, I have a Python3 socket server running with code almost taken directly from https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html.

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
"""
The request handler class for our server.

It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
override the handle() method to implement communication to the
client.
"""

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print(self.data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 1556

   # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
   with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
       # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
       # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
       server.serve_forever()
```

On the client side, I have a simple Python3 program that just sends hello world.

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect(('localhost', 1556))
    print(sock.sendall(bytes('hello world', 'utf-8')))
```

When I connect the client to the server directly, I see the "hello world" message on the server side:

```
b'hello world'
```

With PuTTY SSH tunneling enabled and the client going from localhost:1556 to the server through the tunnel, I receive 0 bytes:

```
b''
```

The client connects to the server but no data is sent with SSH tunneling, and I'm not sure exactly why.

plink command-line arguments:

```
plink -ssh -L 1556:localhost:1556 192.168.1.5
```

Comment: Thanks! By "without PuTTY running" I meant when I modify the code to directly connect the client to the server via the server's IP address, I receive the "hello world" message. When I modify it back to using the SSH tunnel (i.e. go from client localhost:1556 to server localhost:1556), the connection goes through, but I receive no data. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Show us your PuTTY configuration. Or even better, show us a Plink command-line that creates the tunnel.

Comment: Here is plink command-line:
plink -ssh -L 1556:localhost:1556 192.168.1.5

Comment: Did you try to loop in the `handle`? Calling `recv` repeatedly, until the connection closes.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the same problem, probably you forgot to `encode()` and `decode()` your messages. Here is a socket example that works.

Client:

```
import socket

ip = "192.168.xxx.yyy" # replace your ip address

# connect to server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ip, 8080))
print("CLIENT: connected")

# send a message
msg = "I am CLIENT"
client.send(msg.encode())

# recive a message and print it
from_server = client.recv(4096).decode()
print("Recieved: " + from_server)

# exit
client.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket

ip = "192.168.xxx.yyy" # replace your ip address

# start server
serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind((ip, 8080))
serv.listen(5)
print("SERVER: started")

while True:
    # establish connection
    conn, addr = serv.accept()
    from_client = ''
    print("SERVER: connection to Client established")

    while True:
        # receive data and print
        data = conn.recv(4096).decode()
        if not data: break
        from_client += data
        print("Recieved: " + from_client)

        # send message back to client
        msg = "I am SERVER"
        conn.send(msg.encode())

    # close connection and exit
    conn.close()
    break
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/socket-programming-in-python-client-server-p2p/).